# How can autotuners be smooth?

Tags: sound-effects, vocals

It seems like a lot of autotuners have some jaggedness in them, but what's more ideal is something like that glados voice from portal for characters. After preliminary autotuning, how can a voice be made smooth? Can it only be taken care of during recording? Or is it the quality of the software?

Comment: If the original vocal is close enough, auto-tune can be undetectable. If it's a bad vocal, no amount of tweaking will pull it into shape without being able to hear auto-tune working hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most "auto-tuners" have a setting for how quickly it moves from one note to the next. Just slow it down.

Like tetsujin said, if you're trying to change a lot, or have to fix something really far off the note you want, it's just gonna sound weird.